# How to create an array of zeros in typescript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Currently, I'm using `Array.apply(null, new Array(10)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf, 0);` to create an array of 0.

I'm wondering is there a better (cleaner) way to do this in typescript?

Comment: In plain JS you can do something like `Array(10).fill(0)`.

Comment: Or one of the typed arrays, e. g. `Int32Array(10)` if it’s about numbers only.

Comment: @Xufox *With a polyfill, but definitely the best way to go.

Answer (score 21):

**Update**! This is now supported out of the box (see [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/G4QwTgBOkLwQgmMICeAeAdgVwLYCMBTMAPgAoBGABgEoA6AMwEsAbZ0mgbiA)).

You no longer need to extend the `Array` interface.

Old answer:

You can add to the open `Array<T>` interface to make the `fill` method available. There is a [polyfill for Array.prototype.fill on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) if you want older browser support.

```
interface Array<T> {
    fill(value: T): Array<T>;
}

var arr = Array<number>(10).fill(0);
```

[View on Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/)

Eventually the `fill` method will find its way into the `lib.d.ts` file and you can delete your one (the compiler will warn you when you need to do this).

Answer (score 14):

As of now you can just do

```
const a = new Array<number>(1000).fill(0);
```

Make sure you include `<number>` otherwise it will infer `a`'s type as `any[]`.

Comment: This is driving me crazy.  It fails in the latest typescript compiler.`% tsc --version
Version 3.9.2
% cat ./fill.ts
const a = new Array<number>(1000).fill(0);
% tsc ./fill.ts
fill.ts:1:35 - error TS2339: Property 'fill' does not exist on type 'number[]'.
1 const a = new Array<number>(1000).fill(0);`

Comment: You probably need to change the `target` setting in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: That's right.  Array.fill is ES6, so target must specify ES6.  Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 5):

You could pass an integer argument to the Array constructor, this will return a new JavaScript array with its length property set to that number, plus you can use `.fill` to fill all the elements of an array from index zero.

```js
const data = Array(10).fill(0)
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 4):

Having reviewed the concept of array holes I would do:

```
Array.apply(null, new Array(10)).map(()=> 0);
```

Not a big saving but is some.